# Как получать значения от нескольких одновременно работающих процессов на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, асинхронность, multiprocessing

Доброго времени суток.

Есть код, который одновременно запускает несколько асинхронных процессов по списку. Нужно из каждого процесса получить результат, и обновить статус в базе. Пример кода:

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
import subprocess

def worker_email(keyword, func_result):
    subprocess.Popen(["python", "mongoworker.py", str(keyword)])
    func_result.value = 1
    return True

keywords_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'strawberry']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for keyword in keywords_list:
        # Выполняю задачу
        func_result = Value('i', 0)
        p = Process(target=worker_email, args=(keyword,func_result))
        p.start()
        # Обновляю статус задачи
        if func_result.value == 1:
            stream.update_one({'_id': doc['_id']}, {"$set": {"status": True}}, upsert=False)
```

В чем проблема: если использовать `p.join()`, то все работает, но процессы выполняются по очереди. Если не использовать, то процессы не закрываются, и статус не обновляется. Рабочий вариант - выполнять не код функции, а `subprocess.Popen`, но это выглядит как-то нецензурно.

Собственно, буду рад любому совету :)

Answer (score 1):

Решил переносом соединения в базу и проверки результата в саму функцию-worker. Примерно так:

```
def worker_email(keyword, task_id):

    # Соединяюсь с базой
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
    db = client.admetric
    stream = db.stream

    sleep(10)
    print('Yo:' + keyword)

    # Обновляю статус задачи на "Выполнено" (если все ок) или не меняю статус и отправляю на повторое выполнение (если не ок)
    if True:
        stream.update_one({'_id': task_id}, {"$set": {"status": True}}, upsert=False)

    # Отключаюсь от базы
    client.close()
    return True
```

**UPD:** Более разобранный вариант:

```
def update_status(task_id, func_result):
    # Соединяюсь с базой
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
    db = client.admetric
    stream = db.stream

    # Обновляю статус задачи на "Выполнено" (если все ок) или не меняю статус и отправляю на повторое выполнение (если не ок)
    if func_result:
        stream.update_one({'_id': task_id}, {"$set": {"status": True}}, upsert=False)

    # Отключаюсь от базы
    client.close()

def yo_func(keyword):
    sleep(10)
    print('Yo:' + keyword)
    return True

def worker_email(keyword, task_id):
    update_status(task_id, yo_func(keyword))
```